# How to remove a single array element in a specific object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

i need some help with my Mongo DB request.

This is my document structure:

```
{
 "username" : "firstUser",
 "email" : "first@email.com",
 "subscriptions" : [
     {
         "subscriptionId" : ObjectId("59f972dfdaca9e39487e3bb4"),
         "someOtherFields" : "otherValue",
         "message" : {
             "contact" : [
                 "first@email.com",
                 "second@email.com",
                 "third@email.com"
             ],
             "subject" : "Mailsubject",
             "content" : "Mailcontent"
          }
     },
     {
         "subscriptionId" : ObjectId("59faf26c8a593b25b8a9a8f7"),
         "someOtherFields" : "otherValue",
         "message" : {
             "contact" : [
                 "first@email.com",
                 "second@email.com",
                 "third@email.com"
             ],
             "subject" : "Mailsubject",
             "content" : "Mailcontent"
          }
     }
}
```

Now i need to remove one E-Mail address from the `subscriptions.message.contact` array, where the `subscriptions.subscriptionid` = `ObjectId("59f972dfdaca9e39487e3bb4")`.

I tried something like this:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update({
"subscriptions.subscriptionId" : ObjectId("59f972dfdaca9e39487e3bb4")
},
{
    "$pull" : { "subscriptions": {"message.contact" : "first@email.com" }}
})
```

but it removed all `subscriptions` with this E-Mail address

Does anyone know, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this.

I used `$` operator for identifying the elements in the `subscriptions` array.

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').update({
"subscriptions.subscriptionId" : ObjectId("59f972dfdaca9e39487e3bb4")
},
{
    "$pull" : {"subscriptions.$.message.contact" :"first@email.com"}
}
)
```